# DOM manipulation and Javascript Data Structures: Flat or Structured?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, data-structures

I have a business requirement (which is not going to change) to display about 10,000 items on a page (I don't like it). The items are related via a parent child relationship much like folders, sub folders and files on a disk drive.

I want to build the page in such a way that it is driven by a `javascript` data structure (internal application, `javascript` will always be enabled).

Is it generally better to have a flat data structure where each record contains a link to its parent, or is it generally better to have a structured data structure where each "folder" contains references to "sub folders" and "files"?

Ie:

```
var items = { //flat array
              {id:1, parentId:0}, 
              {id:2, parentId:1},
              {id:3, parentId:1},
              {id:4, parentId:2},
              {id:5, parentId:2}
            };

var items = { //structured
             { id: 1, children: {
               { id: 2, children: {
                 { id: 4 },
                 { id: 5 },
               } },
               { id: 3 },
             } }
            };
```

Off the bat the flat format seems easier on the eyes, but the server will be generating that list so honestly that isn't such a big deal. How would performance compare? With flat, there would need to be much more `DOM` lookups, ie find element with `id=1` and insert `DOM` element for `id=2`. The structured format has all the relationships defined so as the `javascript` code is navigating the structure it can create all the `DOM` elements needed without additional lookups. So which method would generally be more performant?

Answer (score 0):

Structured. It's more scalable and will be easier to manipulate nodes in the DOM with JQuery.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Can you give some more detail as to how it is more scalable? Are there any real world examples or synthetic tests?