# Retrive deep data stucture from database using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, data-structures

I have a data structure like below:

```
Task(id,name,subTasks[Task])
```

But the problem is the subTasks can contain Tasks which have another subTasks. This can run to very deep like this:

```
Task1 Contains SubTask1

SubTask1 contains it's sub tasks
```

and you can understand this can be run to very deep.

I can retrieve these data from a database tables. But how can I store this in a data structure in java script. Using for loops without knowing the deep is useless and not a elegant way. What would be the best data structure and data traversal way?

Comment: just store them as json objects, they can be as deep as you want.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Traverse to the deepest using Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18591636/traverse-to-the-deepest-using-java)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to transfer arbitrarily-nested data structures to and from some *other* program (perhaps written in some other language), JSON format is a good format, which can be easily read or written in JavaScript -- see [JSON objects in JavaScript](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/JavaScript/Handling_JSON).
But there is no need for JSON if you're going to create and use such structures entirely internally in a single JavaScript program.

The general technique to traverse arbitrarily nested data structures is [recursion](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/25052/in-plain-english-what-is-recursion).
(Some people claim that "recursion" is one of the 2 most important things to learn about programming, even though they are not needed in 90% of written code
-- [Spolsky](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/ThePerilsofJavaSchools.html), [Tim Bray](http://www.tbray.org/ongoing/When/200x/2005/12/30/Spolsky-Recursion), [Jeff Atwood](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/07/separating-programming-sheep-from-non-programming-goats.html), [Wenham](https://sites.google.com/site/yacoset/Home/signs-that-you-re-a-bad-programmer), [Sooriamurthi](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.25.3778&rep=rep1&type=pdf), etc.
)

There are many stackoverflow questions that discuss [recursion in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/recursion+javascript).
You will get *much* better answers if you read a few of them, write a little bit of code, test it, and then post a short bit of code -- it doesn't have to be perfect.

```
// define the "Task" class
function Task(id, name, depth){
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.depth = depth;
    this.subTask = []; // Use "[]" rather than "{}" so it works with "forEach".
    this.stringify_name_and_all_subtasks = function(depth){
        var return_string = this.depth + ":" + this.name + " ";
        // If "forEach" doesn't work for you,
        // use the "Compatibility" code in
        // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach
        this.subTask.forEach( function(entry){
            return_string += entry.stringify_name_and_all_subtasks(depth);
        });
        return return_string;
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

All too often, programmers try to force the data to fit into a strict hierarchy,
with nested data structures. ( 
[DOM manipulation and Javascript Data Structures: Flat or Structured?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6681660/dom-manipulation-and-javascript-data-structures-flat-or-structured) , 
[Hierarchy Considered Harmful](http://www.communitywiki.org/en/HierarchyConsideredHarmful), etc. )

However, non-nested structures are better when you don't have a pure hierarchy.
Sometimes they work better even when you do have a pure hierarchy --
such as when you want to look up things without traversing the entire structure.
For example,
"What tasks depend on the sub-task named 'rotate stock' ?"

Perhaps one of the many [alternatives to hierarchy](http://www.communitywiki.org/en/AlternativesToHierarchy)
might work better in your case.
For example, an associative array:

```
<script>
"use strict";
// global task list
var tasklist_by_id = [];
var task_name_to_id = {};

// add a new task to global tasklist
function add_task(id, name, supertaskid){
    tasklist_by_id[ id ] = {"id":id, "name":name, "supertaskid":supertaskid};
    /* in other words,
    var new_task = {};
    new_task.id = id;
    new_task.name = name;
    new_task.supertaskid = supertaskid;
    tasklist_by_id[ id ] = new_task;
    */
    task_name_to_id[ name ] = id;
};

function ancestors_of( task_id ){
    if( task_id ){
        var my_name =  tasklist_by_id[ task_id ].name;
        var my_supertaskid = tasklist_by_id[task_id].supertaskid;
        var my_ancestors = ancestors_of( my_supertaskid );
        var ancestor_string = " -- " + my_name + my_ancestors;
        return ancestor_string;
    }else{
        return ".";
    };
};

function test(){
    add_task( 1, "Main task #1", 0 );
    add_task( 2, "Subtask 1", task_name_to_id[ "Main task #1" ] );
    add_task( 3, "Sub-subtask 1", task_name_to_id[ "Subtask 1" ] );
    add_task( 4, "Another Subtask of Main task 1", task_name_to_id[ "Main task #1" ] );
add_task( 5, "Sub-sub-subtask 1", task_name_to_id[ "Sub-subtask 1" ] );
    add_task( 6, "rotate_stock", task_name_to_id["Sub-sub-subtask 1" ])

    // What task is the parent task(s) of "rotate_stock" ?

    var some_task_name = "rotate_stock";
    var some_task_id = task_name_to_id[some_task_name];
    var ancestors = ancestors_of( some_task_id );

    alert("The ancestry line of " + some_task_name + " is " + ancestors);
}

test();
</script>
```